# NullPointerException problems

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a method that makes a JFrame visible, but i dont know why i cant run my program.

```
https://imgur.com/a/WcQ7SHw

 these are the error lines: 



   // here im calling to the method VentanaAlta to fill a combobox
//(errorline 21)

 public VentanaAlta() {
        initComponents();
        Main.llenarCombobox(cbPuesto);
    }



// here im trying to fill a combobox with Objetcs
//(errorline 41)-

public static void llenarCombobox(JComboBox comboPuesto){

      for(int x = 0; aPuestos.length > x; x++){

             comboPuesto.addItem(aPuestos[x].getNombrePuesto());
             comboPuesto.setSelectedItem(-1);
}


//this is a method that is called in the first line on the Main class (maybe //the problem is here, and yes, vAltas is a global variable)

//(errorline 95)

   public static void crearVentana(){
        vAltas = new VentanaAlta();
        vAltas.setVisible(true);             
    }


//(errorline 32)
llenarCombobox();
```

In the code you will see comments that shows the errorlines.

I have tried to be clear with the image and with the code comments, sorry for my englis i did my best.

Global Variables.
aPersonas arrayList.
cbPuesto is a combobox.
llenarCombobox(cbPuesto); its the method to fill the combobox.

Comment: VentanaAlta is not a method i mean llenarCombobox();

Comment: Have you tested to see which variable on the offending line is null? You *must* do this first

Comment: Okay im idiot haha, i solved it, the problem is that i was trying to fill the combobox with the objets before create the objets haha so sorry.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on debugging your code.